Should I be worried?
I recently started a job in staffing and got transitioned to nights. I worked a few weeks and then I was hit with meeting request from my manager. The meeting was for Monday (today), in the meeting she brought up several allegations towards me.The list included being found asleep,not working of a specific document, not being timely and not responding to co workers via chat… Now you have the background on the issue, I will tell my part.
I have never been found asleep… taken a small rest for ten or fifteen minutes maybe (not an every shift deal) I work 12 hours w no break or meal break… and was only told today how I should take my break when I’ve been on nights for a month. So yes 1 night out of 15 nights ,I get tired! I have never been found asleep because this only happened once… when I worked from home… yes this one might be on me 100 % but the others are not. As far as not working on the specific document, there is a mid shift person who is more seasoned on the job and they take the job over.. never asking me to help or collaborate… then I get blamed for their issues or simply told on I’m not doing it? I have screenshots where I have reached out to the mid shift person to help with the documents but by the time they read my chat and respond (typically 20 minutes PLUS) they have already completed it. I suppose nothing is wrong with that and I should just take the blame because I’m there all night? NO!! If I didn’t do it I shouldn’t be getting blamed, especially when I have tried to make it a group effort. Not to mention we have a call queue that I’m the only person on for 12 straight hours, but this isn’t a problem… so when I don’t respond to a co-workers chat bc I’m having to take their calls and mine… i don’t feel bad ab that.
Trust me, I know the falling asleep is a fireable offense but working 12 hours w no break is also against the law… just wondering if I should leave the job or stick it out? It sounds like they have their mind made up on me so I’m just trying to be proactive. I don’t want to leave solely because it makes me look guilty but I absolutely don’t want them to have the upper hand and fire me. I work at a hospital in a at will state… so I kinda know where this is going… thanks yall!

Please. Add. Paragraphs.

@PhilipKendall DONE, would you like to provide an answer now?? If not, thanks for the editing suggestion.

Is this a question or a rant? Most of this is you defending your actions to us but it doesn't matter if we think you're in the wrong or not, your job obviously does. Its hard to say if you should leave or not, we don't know your circumstances (What income will you have if you leave? How easily will you find a new job? Are other people depending on your income?)

I will say that you shouldn't worry about "looking guilty" people leave jobs for many reasons. At the same time you got disciplined once, its not the end of the world, if you get some clarification from your manager about where you're not seeing eye-to-eye and put in a little more effort I think you'll be fine.

@InBedded16 This isn’t necessarily a question or a rant; I’m just interested in hearing how others would handle a similar situation or if they’ve had comparable experiences. I thought this was a discussion board where we could share perspectives. Thanks for the response! Will wait it out and see the resolution.

@gazingmoonz This is off topic by your own admission that this is not a question. Please read up about what is on topic.

@gazingmoonz: this needs a location tag. In many countries 12 hours without break is indeed illegal. If that's the case, you should be pushing back on that fact.

@Hilmar according to the second paragraph OP was told they should in fact be taking a break(s) during this shift, for some reason they didn't know this until recently.

@InBedded16 yes! this because we work off a time checklist! Breaks are done during a certain time (coverage permitting) and during the times there was not adequate staff to allow for me to break. I have been working 12 hours w no breaks per their break policy.

@JoeStrazzere I want to clarify that they never walked in and found me passed out. I took a 10-minute nap while working from home.

"I took a 10-minute nap while working from home." then how do they know?

They always have the upper hand no matter what. If they wanted to fire you, they would; without much hesitation, so worrying is of no use. Keep doing what you doing and do not let them have a reason to point the finger at you.


just wondering if I should leave the job or stick it out?

If you aren't able to complete the job without falling asleep, you should probably be looking for your next job - perhaps a day job.
I never recommend quitting one job before having a new job to go to.

I understand your concern. However, the 10-minute nap was not a reoccurring problem and occurred after working 12 hours straight without a break. This doesn’t reflect my usual performance. I appreciate your advice and will definitely keep it in mind.

@gazingmoonz - Why are you working without a break for 12 hours? You most certainly are in a country where they are required to provide a break of some kind, but of course your question doesn’t have the necessary information to determine if that’s the case, so you probably should edit it to include that type of information

I don't know where you live, where I live 12 hours without a break is so illegal, even the exceptions from the law do not cover it any more.
But anyway, instead of lamenting how unfair something is, or telling you that it is or isn't unfair, lets talk about what you can do better next time, because realistically, that is the only thing you can control.
Next time, you ask for their rules on taking breaks on shifts. On day one!
Everyone needs to use the restroom or eat during a 12 hour shift. Instead of being tired not taking breaks, or taking your own breaks out of neccessity, ask for the rules and follow them. That is what good employees do.
In the meantime, for now, apologize, ask for the official rules and follow them from now on. If you feel you don't need to apologize for taking a nap, apologize for not asking for the proper procedure of taking break. But you did something wrong. If you protest instead of seeing your error, they will have no choice but to let you go.
